# data reload angularjs on event binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a table which will get the data from api call as below. Now I have added a button which should get the latest data from api but getting duplicates as it is fetching data again. Can anyone please correct me with the correct logic

```js
var getData = function() {
  $http.get('/data').success(function (data, status) {
    $scope.apiData = data;
    //manipulate();
  })
}


$scope.reload = function()
{
  $scope.apiData = {};
  getData();
}
```

Comment: post processData method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initilaize the array to empty within the method, so that it wont get duplicaed

```
  $scope.apiData = [];
```

Comment: I tried to set it to empty when refresh is clicked but still get duplicates. please look at the updated question

Answer (score 1):

Refresh `$scope.apiData` after `$http.get` response

```
var getData = function() {
  $http.get('/data').success(function (data, status) {
    $scope.apiData = {};
    $scope.apiData = data;
    processTable();
  })
}
```